# Ubuntu 18.10 only login with Ubuntu Wayland

Tags: nvidia, login

Ok, so I tried to update my Nvidia graphics drivers and I successfully did so but there seems to be a problem with gdm3. I can only login via Ubuntu Wayland or else I'm getting a login loop. Any ideas why this might be happening?